# How can I combine two contour plots into one and give it a bar legend?

Tags: plotting

I have these contour plots:

```
ContourPlot[
 TC, {y, 0.02, 5}, {\[ScriptCapitalA], 0, 0.3},
  PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[y, FontSize -> 14, Blue], 
   Style[\[ScriptCapitalA], FontSize -> 14, Blue]}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Dashed}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 9}, 
 ContourShading -> {White, Lighter[Blue, 0.9], Lighter[Blue, 0.7], 
   Lighter[Blue, 0.5], Lighter[Blue, 0.3], Lighter[Blue, 0.1], 
   Darker[Blue, 0.2], Darker[Blue, 0.4], Black}, 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &)]
```

and

```
ContourPlot[
TC, {y, 0.02, 5}, {\[ScriptCapitalA], -0.3, 
  0}, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[y, FontSize -> 14, Blue], 
   Style[\[ScriptCapitalA], FontSize -> 14, Blue]}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Dashed}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 9}, 
 ContourShading -> {White, Lighter[Blue, 0.9], Lighter[Blue, 0.7], 
   Lighter[Blue, 0.5], Lighter[Blue, 0.3], Lighter[Blue, 0.1], 
   Darker[Blue, 0.2], Darker[Blue, 0.4], Black}, 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &)]
```

where

```
TC=-1 + 0.18240901220588282*E^y*
   Sqrt[(-0.042 + 0.028*y)/(E^(2*y)*y) + 
     1.742955604211617*(2*BesselI[0, y] + y*BesselI[1, y])*
      BesselK[0, y] - 1.742955604211617*(y*BesselI[0, y] + 
       BesselI[1, y])*BesselK[1, y]] - 
  (0.05450511749722444*(0.042 - 0.028*y + (3 - 2*y)*\[ScriptCapitalA] + 
     ((-0.168 + 0.112*y)*\[ScriptCapitalA])/E^(2*y) - 1.834690109696439*
      E^(2*y)*y*BesselI[1, y]*(y*BesselK[0, y] - 
       1.*BesselK[1, y]) + 7.338760438785756*y*\[ScriptCapitalA]*
      BesselI[1, y]*(y*BesselK[0, y] - 1.*BesselK[1, y]) + 
     1.834690109696439*E^(2*y)*y*BesselI[0, y]*
      (-2.*BesselK[0, y] + y*BesselK[1, y]) - 
     7.338760438785756*y*\[ScriptCapitalA]*BesselI[0, y]*
      (-2.*BesselK[0, y] + y*BesselK[1, y]) - 
     7.338760438785756*E^(2*y)*y*\[ScriptCapitalA]*
      (2*(BesselI[0, 2*y] + y*BesselI[1, 2*y])*
        BesselK[0, 2*y] - (2*y*BesselI[0, 2*y] + 
         BesselI[1, 2*y])*BesselK[1, 2*y])))/y + 
  (6.514607578781529*E^(3*y)*\[ScriptCapitalA]*
    ((2*(0.042 - 0.028*y + E^(2*y)*y*BesselI[1, y]*
         (-1.834690109696439*y*BesselK[0, y] + 
          1.834690109696439*BesselK[1, y]) + 
        E^(2*y)*y*BesselI[0, y]*(-3.669380219392878*
           BesselK[0, y] + 1.834690109696439*y*
           BesselK[1, y]))*(0.0023520000000000004 - 
        0.042*E^(2*y) - 0.0015680000000000002*y + 
        0.028*E^(2*y)*y + 0.9173450548482195*E^(2*y)*
         (-0.112 + E^(2*y))*y*BesselI[1, y]*
         (y*BesselK[0, y] - 1.*BesselK[1, y]) - 
        0.9173450548482195*E^(2*y)*(-0.112 + E^(2*y))*y*
         BesselI[0, y]*(-2.*BesselK[0, y] + 
          y*BesselK[1, y]) + 0.051371323071500295*E^(4*y)*y*
         BesselI[1, 2*y]*(2*y*BesselK[0, 2*y] - 
          BesselK[1, 2*y]) - 0.10274264614300059*E^(4*y)*y*
         BesselI[0, 2*y]*(-1.*BesselK[0, 2*y] + 
          y*BesselK[1, 2*y])))/E^(8*y) + 
     (0.09173450548482195*y*
       (-((BesselI[1, y]*(y*BesselK[0, y] - BesselK[1, y]) + 
           BesselI[0, y]*(2*BesselK[0, y] - 
             y*BesselK[1, y]))*(0.0023520000000000004 - 
           0.042*E^(2*y) - 0.0015680000000000002*y + 
           0.028*E^(2*y)*y + 0.9173450548482195*E^(2*y)*
            (-0.112 + E^(2*y))*y*BesselI[1, y]*
            (y*BesselK[0, y] - 1.*BesselK[1, y]) - 
           0.9173450548482195*E^(2*y)*(-0.112 + E^(2*y))*y*
            BesselI[0, y]*(-2.*BesselK[0, y] + 
             y*BesselK[1, y]) + 0.051371323071500295*E^(4*y)*
            y*BesselI[1, 2*y]*(2*y*BesselK[0, 2*y] - 
             BesselK[1, 2*y]) - 0.10274264614300059*E^(4*y)*
            y*BesselI[0, 2*y]*(-1.*BesselK[0, 2*y] + 
             y*BesselK[1, 2*y]))) + 
        (0.042 - 0.028*y + E^(2*y)*y*BesselI[1, y]*
           (-1.834690109696439*y*BesselK[0, y] + 
            1.834690109696439*BesselK[1, y]) + 
          E^(2*y)*y*BesselI[0, y]*(-3.669380219392878*
             BesselK[0, y] + 1.834690109696439*y*
             BesselK[1, y]))*(-1.*(-0.112 + E^(2*y))*
           BesselI[1, y]*(y*BesselK[0, y] - 
            1.*BesselK[1, y]) - (-0.112 + E^(2*y))*
           BesselI[0, y]*(2*BesselK[0, y] - 
            y*BesselK[1, y]) - 0.112*E^(2*y)*
           (BesselI[1, 2*y]*(2*y*BesselK[0, 2*y] - 
              BesselK[1, 2*y]) + 2*BesselI[0, 2*y]*
             (BesselK[0, 2*y] - y*BesselK[1, 2*y])))))/
      E^(6*y)))/(y*Sqrt[(-0.042 + 0.028*y)/(E^(2*y)*y) + 
      BesselI[1, y]*(1.834690109696439*y*BesselK[0, y] - 
        1.834690109696439*BesselK[1, y]) + 
      BesselI[0, y]*(3.669380219392878*BesselK[0, y] - 
        1.834690109696439*y*BesselK[1, y])]*
    ((0.042 - 0.028*y)/E^(2*y) - 1.834690109696439*y*
      BesselI[1, y]*(y*BesselK[0, y] - 1.*BesselK[1, y]) + 
     1.834690109696439*y*BesselI[0, y]*(-2.*BesselK[0, y] + 
       y*BesselK[1, y])))
```

Now, the question is, how can I merge the $y$-axis?
Moreover, is it possible to add a bar-legend including the same colors as above plots?

Note that, this question is edited after adding a comment and an answer. In fact, here I have brought the original form of the function which should be plotted (i.e. $TC$). Sorry for these complicated inputs.

Comment: Why not use a single `ContourPlot` call? Just set `ContourStyle` appropriately, and use `Contours` to set the correct amount of contours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way the two contour plots can be combined and given a bar legend.

```
With[{n = 15},
  Module[{colors},
    colors = 
      Join[{White}, (Lighter[Blue, #] & /@ Subdivide[1, 0, n])[[3 ;; -3]], {Black}];
    ContourPlot[1 + \[ScriptCapitalA] (η y + μ η y^2 + 1) /. {η -> 0.01, μ -> 0.014},
      {y, 0.02, 5}, {\[ScriptCapitalA], -.3, .3},
      AspectRatio -> 1.5,
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 9},
      FrameLabel -> 
         {Style[y, FontSize -> 14, Blue], Style[\[ScriptCapitalA], 
          FontSize -> 14, Blue]},
      Contours -> 
        Function[{min, max}, Range[Floor[min, .05], Ceiling[max, .05], .05]],
      ContourStyle -> {Dashed},
      ContourShading -> colors, 
      ContourLabels -> 
        (Text[Framed[Round[#3, .01]], {#1, #2}, Background -> White]&),
      PlotLegends -> Automatic,
      ImageSize -> {Automatic, 600}]]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Decorating plots is more an art than a science. When you change the content of a plot you should always expect to tweak the decorations.

For your expression, `TC`, you need to adjust the parameters controlling the plotting of the contours. Here is how I did it. Basically all I did was increase the size of interval between contours to something reasonable for `TC`.

```
With[{n = 18}, 
  Module[{colors}, 
    colors =
      Join[{White}, (Lighter[Blue, #] & /@ Subdivide[1, 0, n])[[3 ;; -3]], {Black}];
    ContourPlot[TC, {y, 0.02, 5}, {\[ScriptCapitalA], -.3, .3},
      AspectRatio -> 1.5,
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 9}, 
      FrameLabel -> 
        {Style[y, FontSize -> 14, Blue], Style[\[ScriptCapitalA], 
         FontSize -> 14, Blue]}, 
      Contours -> 
       Function[{min, max}, Range[Floor[min, 1.5], Ceiling[max, 1.5], 1.5]], 
      ContourStyle -> {Dashed},
      ContourShading -> colors,
      PlotLegends -> Automatic,
      ImageSize -> {Automatic, 600}]]]
```

[image: plot]

**Notes**

1. It may look as if full range of colors does not appear, but it does. Look very carefully at the upper-right corner to see the bit of black that appears there.
2. I have removed the contour labeling because Mathematica's automatic positioning of such labels is very ugly on this plot. Even manual positioning of the labels would be difficult for these contours because of the way the they bunch up at the upper-right and lower-right corners. The default tooltip labeling takes over, but of course won't work if the plot is posted or printed. You might choose install custom labels at only those contours that have plenty of room for them, but don't ask me to write the code for that.
3. As for "more distinguishable colors", that is an aesthetic or psychological question, not a Mathematica question. I will point out, however, that the variable `colors` can be any list of colors, so experimenting with alternative colors is not difficult.

Comment: Dear m, sorry, this solution didn't work out for the original form of the function. Would you please kindly recheck for $TC$? Thanks. Moreover, I need more distinguishable colors :(

Comment: @PerfectFluid. I have made an update that shows adjustments that accommodate `TC`.

Comment: Thank you. Why "psychological" :)) The point is, I want the colors to be more different in each contour in order to be more distinguishable in a black and white print. I think it is a technical task and may be possible. By the way, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @PerfectFluid. I meant that different people see colors differently. Maybe "psychological" was the wrong word, perhaps "physiological" would be better. If your final reproduction is to be in B&W, I suggest experimenting with GrayLevel for the contour shading.

Answer (score 0):

To have more distinguishable colors, the updated version of `m_goldberg`'s answer maybe

```
With[{n = 18}, 
 Module[{colors}, 
  colors = Join[{White}, (Lighter[Blue, #] & /@ 
       Subdivide[1, 0, n])[[3 ;; -3]], {Black}];
  ContourPlot[TC, {y, 0.02, 5}, {\[ScriptCapitalA], -.3, .3}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1.5, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 9}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style[y, FontSize -> 14, Blue], 
     Style[\[ScriptCapitalA], FontSize -> 14, Blue]}, 
   Contours -> 
    Function[{min, max}, 
     Range[Floor[min, 1.5], Ceiling[max, 1.5], 1.5]], 
   ContourStyle -> {Dashed}, 
   ContourShading -> {Black, Darker[Red, 0.6], Darker[Red, 0.4], 
     Darker[Red, 0.2], Lighter[Red, 0.4], Lighter[Red, 0.75], 
     Lighter[Red, 0.9], Lighter[Blue, 0.9], Lighter[Blue, 0.75], 
     Lighter[Blue, 0.6], Lighter[Blue, 0.4], Lighter[Blue, 0.2], Blue,
      Darker[Blue, 0.2], Darker[Blue, 0.4], Darker[Blue, 0.6], 
     Darker[Blue, 0.8]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 600}]]]
```

[image: The output is like that.]